# Why won't this JavaScript work in FF4?

Tags: javascript

My custom implementation of the Yahoo Media Player works great in all the major browsers. Except for Firefox 4.

I've tried to use Firebug and the debugging tools in Firefox, but I can't see any errors. It's like the file isn't even executing.

Please refer to the play buttons on any of the following sites (same implementation):

- http://lizebeekman.co.za/lullabies.html
- http://RhythmMusicStore.com/store/ (I know the coding is old and horrible)
- http://rock.co.za/files/top40_sa_rock_legends.html

If you can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Right now, I have no idea where the error is. Instructions for how to spot the error using FF's debugging tools would also be helpful.

Comment: You may wish to migrate this question to Stack Overflow. It's a bit off topic on Code Review (ie. you're trouble shooting, not requesting a peer review of your script). Also, it is good manners to include the code you would like assistance with in the body of your question.

Comment: @65Fbe05,  thanks. This is my first post on Code Review - not down on the protocol yet. I would post on SO, but I think it will be flagged as belonging on "Code Review". In this particular case, I would post the offending script if I knew which part was the problem. I can't post *everything* or a whole JS file if I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Code Review is not for [troubleshooting code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq). I'm migrating this to SO where it is on-topic.